# Is the phrase "might have not been able to~" grammatically wrong?

Tags: verbs

Is the phrase "might have not been able to~" grammatically wrong? If it's wrong, why is that?

Comment: So long as it's used within a sentence correctly, it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is perfectly correct.

A quick search on Google found the [Science magazine](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/11/ancient-flying-reptiles-cared-their-young-fossil-trove-suggests) using this phrase:

> ... the evidence suggests that hatchlings **might have not been able to** hunt for themselves, relying on their parents to feed them

Another example:

> From where he was standing, he **might not have been able to** see the tree.

"might" adds a condition while "have not been able to" uses the present perfect tense.

Answer (score 0):

"Might have not been able" is grammatical, but it is far less idiomatic than "might not have been able." It is usual for the negation to follow immediately after the first modal in a modalized verb.